# Rendering application.html.erb as a default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If an index.html.erb file is not in a directory for a model e.g. User, rails will look in the views/application directory for it.

```
views/user
    *no index.html.erb file*
views/application
    index.html.erb
```

This fall back automatically happens if there is no explicit render request in a controller.

However this doesn't seem to work if I do

```
render 'users/index'
```

which results in a "Template is missing" error.

Is there a way to request a render which will fall back to the views/application directory if it doesn't find it in the model's view directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a protected method `render_with_fallback` and use existing private method `default_template_name` like this:

```
def render_with_fallback(name, options = {})
  view = template_exists?(name) ? name : default_template_name
  render(view, options)
end
```